# For the given endomorphism calculate $\varphi^{106}(1,1,4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have an endomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\varphi(0,1,1)=(0,1,1), \varphi(2,2,0)=(0,0,0), \varphi(1,0,0)=(-1,0,0)$. I want to calculate $\varphi^{106}(1,1,4)$.

I start by making up a matrix A:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then I calculate eigenvalues using $(A-I\lambda) = 0$ which is true for $\lambda=\{-1, 0, 1\}$. I finish up with eigenvectors:

$$C=\{[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, -1]\}$$

What do I do next and is this the correct start to this solution?

Comment: Note that $(1,1,4)=4\times (0,1,1)-\frac 32\times (2,2,0)-2\times (1,0,0)$.

Comment: Whith what you have you can find easily the diagonalization $A=PDP^{-1}$. Now apply the $106th$ power to get $A^{106}=PD^{106}P^{-1}$ and finaly compute $A^{106}(1,1,4)^t$ which is the value you want.

Comment: I think you've got the wrong matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1=(0,1,1)$, $v_2=(2,2,0)$, and $v_3=(1,0,0)$. Then,

- since $\varphi(v_1)=v_1$, $\varphi^{106}(v_1)=v_1$;
- since $\varphi(v_2)=0$, $\varphi^{106}(v_2)=0$;
- since $\varphi(v_3)=-v_3$, $\varphi^{106}(v_3)=v_3$.

And now, since$$(1,1,4)=4v_1-\frac32v_2+4v_3,$$you have\begin{align}\varphi^{106}(1,1,4)&=\varphi^{106}\left(4v_1-\frac32v_2+4v_3\right)\\&=4v_1+4v_3\\&=(4,4,4).\end{align}